# Highcharts with live data: align chart on left side

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm working with highcharts and live data. I saw this example, and it works fine for me:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

but when first data arrives, it draws the point in the middle of the chart:
[image]

The graph looks ok when it is filled with data:[image]

but I want to align the line on the left, even if I have few points to draw. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem here is in the `maxZoom` attribute of a `xAxis` object. Using it you can specify a minimal range of `xAxis`, that has been there: `maxZoom` was set to `20000`. To get point aligned to the left you can just remove this attribute from your configuration. Here is my edited version of this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arcquim/y9eaw1rf/13/.

By the way, [`maxZoom`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.maxZoom) is deprecated and replaced with new [`minRange`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minRange) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the maxZoom (minRange actually) property, you need to set axis min on the first point's addition and when you start shifting points - you should reset min, so the chart will be able to change its extremes.

```
      load: function() {

    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var chart = this;
    var series = this.series[0];
    var minSet = false;
    var extremesReset = false;

    setInterval(function() {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

      if (!minSet) {
        chart.xAxis[0].update({
          min: x
        }, false);
        minSet = true;
      }

      if (series.data.length > 20 && !extremesReset) {
        chart.xAxis[0].update({
          min: null,
        }, false)
        extremesReset = true;
      }

      series.addPoint([x, y], true, series.data.length > 20, series.data.length);

    }, 1000);
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xbrwqk46/